# Cmake Mechanism for making makefile in windows

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, mingw

I am working on Qt and cmake so I want to know how cmake generate makefile. I analysis makefile that generated by cmake but i founded that cmake call cmake command again in the makefile insted  of using gcc or cl command for building projects. In other word how cmake execute gcc compiler for building executable file?

Comment: You are not supposed to fumble around with the generated Makefiles. Probably you have a problem. Ask about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

CMake creates the make-files or project files but it does not trigger any compiler step. For a description see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)

As the question is tagged with mingw I assume this is your environment. Thus the steps are:

1. Write your CMakeList.txt
2. Create and switch into your build directory: **mkdir build**
3. Create make-files using cmake: **cmake PATH\TO\YOUR\SOURCES**
4. Build the project: **make** or **nmake**